# Sending Array of Images on Server ?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, batch-processing

I have tried all the options available on net for batch sending images to server . I am using AFNetworking but can't find AFHttpClient. I am not able to send the images to server .

Let me know the function to send images to server .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AFHTTPClient` is a AFNetworking 1.x class. You want to use `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` or `AFHTTPSessionManager` now.

See the [1.x to 2.x migration guide](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-2.0-Migration-Guide)

---

You asked to how upload these files. It depends entirely upon how your server code was written, but assuming that your server is using standard `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` technique (e.g. if using PHP code that references `$_FILES` variable), you could use `constructingBodyWithBlock` variation of `POST`:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://path/to/image.png"];
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath1 name:@"image" error:nil];
    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath2 name:@"image" error:nil];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

You can use `appendPartWithFormData`, too.

Comment: Yeah i am using AFHTTPRequestOperationManager , but how to send multiple images by this ?

Comment: See code sample in revised answer. This is a permutation of the example given on AFNetworking's github page.

Comment: In this .. i have to predefine the number of images i have to send. 
I Have an Array of Images .How to send that . In this above Code. you have hard coded 2 image path . I don't want that .

Comment: Can i run a loop on     [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath1 name:@"image" error:nil];
 ??

Comment: Yep, you could do a `for` loop. It doesn't have to be hard-coded.

Comment: I am getting 302 HTTP Error . I have implemented loop
'for (UIImage *image in billImageArray) {
                NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
                [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"attachment" fileName:@"attachment.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
            }'

Comment: I suspect error is unrelated to loop, but don't see anything that would cause any such problem. But there is unrelated problem: You specified PNG extension and mime type, but created JPG representation. Use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` to match your use of PNG elsewhere. In terms of 302 error, are you absolutely sure the server code works and supports uploading of multiple images in single request? Have you tried it with single image?

Comment: Yeah I have tried with single image . Its perfectly working fine. But i am not able to do it same for Multiple Images . Thanks for your support :) . i Appreciated it a lot .

Comment: It could well be the server code. Many implementations don't expect multiple images to be uploaded in a single request.

Comment: Please see to this link , i have added the log which is delivered on SERVER [http://pastebin.com/4gfr3519]

Comment: @Rob, as above log i need array of attachment parameter. Currently it's coming only one that to not in array, "attachment"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb9e8b48 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20141215-12209-dd1fn8>, @original_filename="attachment.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachment\"; filename=\"attachment.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">

Comment: I'd suggest you post a new question with your server code as we've gone beyond the scop of this original question and it's really hard to follow what you're saying (your snippet is gone, your attachment log is hard to read in comments, etc.).

Comment: @RubyOnRails---- Any solution found to your issue even i am facing the same issue??